# Change variable's value based on time frame

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create an indicator that changes its hline value based on time frame. But I can't figure out why it's not working. Please help.

```html
//@version=5

indicator(title="my indicator", precision=4)

obLvl1_Line = 0.02
obLvl2_Line = 0.04

if timeframe.period == "D"
    obLvl1_Line = 0.02
    obLvl2_Line = 0.04


if timeframe.period == "240"
    obLvl1_Line = 0.006
    obLvl2_Line = 0.010


if timeframe.period == "60"
    obLvl1_Line = 0.0030
    obLvl2_Line = 0.0040
 
obLvl1_fill = hline(obLvl1_Line, color=color.new(#00bcd4, 50), linestyle=hline.style_dotted, linewidth=1) 
obLvl2_fill = hline(obLvl2_Line, color=color.new(color.green, 100), linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=2)

fill(obLvl1_fill, obLvl2_fill, color=color.new(#00bcd4, 94), title="OverBought BG")

plot(obLvl1_Line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `:=` must be used to give a new value to a variable. Hence, every variable reassignment under an if block should use `:=`.

```
if timeframe.period == "D"
    obLvl1_Line := 0.02
    obLvl2_Line := 0.04

if timeframe.period == "240"
    obLvl1_Line := 0.006
    obLvl2_Line := 0.010

if timeframe.period == "60"
    obLvl1_Line := 0.0030
    obLvl2_Line := 0.0040
```